# Separating a term from a power in overleaf

Tags: latex, equation, overleaf

I have used this code to type an equation in overleaf but the bolded part becomes a part of the power. Is there a way to separate it?

\begin{multline}
u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\frac{\mu}{\rho} \frac{m}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]^\left(\frac{m}{2}-1\right) **\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)**
\end{multline}

Need the bolded part to be separated from the power and let it be in the equation as a multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal compilable example, I am assuming that you are using the the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\frac{\mu}{\rho} \frac{m}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]^{\left(\frac{m}{2}-1\right)} \left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}\right) \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I used `^{...}` to separate the exponent from the remaining term:
`^{\left(\frac{m}{2}-1\right)}`
Hope this helps...